# bootstraping my html divs fixed width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have some simple HTML with 4 div columns beside each other with a "spacer" between them what I would like is when the page it shrunken Id like the columns to stay the same width and when they disapear they should show up below is that possible with bootstrap?

here is the html css

```
<html><head>
<style type="text/css">
* {margin: 0; padding: 3px;}
#container {height: 800%; width:900%; font-size: 1;}
.columns,.spacer{display: inline-block; *display: inline; zoom: 0; vertical-align: top; font-size: 12px;}
.columns {background-color: white; width: 300px; height: 700px;}
.columns {box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;}
.spacer {background-color: transparent; width: 1px; height: 1px;}
.footerDIV {box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;}
.footerDIV {background-color: white; width: 620px; height: 100px;font-size: 12px;}
.spacerHorizontal {background-color: transparent; width: 10px; height: 10px; font-size: 12px;}
A{text-decoration:none}
</style>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link href="./bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link href="./bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="./bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- JQ Tools -->
<script src="./jquery.js"></script>
<script src="./jquery.corner.js"></script>


</head>


<body bgcolor="#d6d6d4">
<div id="container">

<div class="row">
 <div class="columns" id="Admissions" style='border-radius: 10px; background-image: url("./green.png"); background-repeat: no-repeat;'>111111111</div>
 <div id=1spacer1 class=spacer style="background-color: #white; width: 3px; height: 4px;"></div>
 <div class="columns" id="Headcount"  style='border-radius: 10px; background-image: url("./green.png"); background-repeat: no-repeat;'>222222222</div>
 <div id=2spacer1 class=spacer style="background-color: #white; width: 3px; height: 4px;"></div>
 <div class="columns" id="Test1"      style='border-radius: 10px; background-image: url("./green.png"); background-repeat: no-repeat;'>333333333</div>
 <div id=3spacer1 class=spacer style="background-color: #white; width: 3px; height: 4px;"></div>
 <div class="columns" id="Test2"      style='border-radius: 10px; background-image: url("./green.png"); background-repeat: no-repeat;'>444444444</div>
 <div id=4spacer1 class=spacer style="background-color: #white; width: 3px; height: 4px;"></div>
</div>




</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by including the bootstrap css and js

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="./bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

and then renaming .columns to use .col-md-3